# Java generics: Multiple bounds with type parameter

Tags: java, generics

The following Java code compiles:

```
interface Interface1{}
interface Interface2{}
class MyClass1<T extends Interface1 & Interface2>{}
```

Also, the following code compiles:

```
class AClass{}
interface Interface3{}
class MyClass2<T extends AClass & Interface3>{}
```

The following code will give me a compile error:

```
interface Interface4 {}
class MyClass3<T, S extends T & Interface4> {}
```

So, as it seems, it is not possible to have multiple bounds if one of the bounding types is itself a type parameter. But why is that?

As I understand, if multiple bounds are declared, at most one of them may be a class (with all others being interfaces), and it must be the first one.

But, since in my example `Interface` is an interface, why does the compiler complain? After all, it shouldn't make any difference whether T is an interface or a class.

I've tried to find an answer online, but apparently my googling skills are not sufficient. I'd love to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 4.4 of the Java language spec seems to explicitly disallow this.  A Type Bound is specified as:

```
TypeBound:
   extends TypeVariable
   extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}

AdditionalBound:
   & InterfaceType
```

So it looks like you can specify a Type Variable ("T"), or you can have a list of classes and interfaces, but you can't mix them.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4

Comment: I understand why they have done this, but having this feature would be really powerful. How would one go about making/requesting this change?